# expand shell variable in ed onliner

Tags: shell, variables, expansion, ed

I want to shorten a log file on a unix system with very limited shell capability. My preferred way to do this would be with `ed`.

Deleting a fix number of lines works fine:

```
ed -s file.txt <<< $'1,4d\nwq'
```

But how can I expand *the number of lines to delete* from a shell variable in a `ed` oneliner? I'm looking for something like:

```
n_del=4; ed -s file.txt <<< $'1,\${n_del}d\nwq'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it’s perfectly normal in shell to just concatenate strings quoted in different ways and even non-quoted, so it may looks like:

```
$ n_del=4; ed -s test <<< "1,${n_del}"d$'\n'wq
```

I believe, here-doc would be more cleaner here, than one-liner:

```
$ n_del=4
$ ed -s test <<_EOF
1,${n_del}d
wq
_EOF
```

Comment: `ed` used to have limits on the size of files that it can process. Maybe thats fixed now. If a problem, the O.P. may want to switch to using `ex` instead. Good luck to all.